# Join tables with fk from XOR

Tags: postgresql, xor

I have a table `judge` where attributes are `id_judge`, `scope` and this table is in **XOR** with tables `global_usercache` (attribute `id_user`) and `global_externaluser` (attribute `id_user`).

So, the table judge has two FK: `gu_id_user` and `eu_id_user`.

I would like to join table `judge` with one of the user tables to get info about the judge (name, etc.).

Is there any possible way to achieve my goal?

Thanks

Edit (sample data):

[image]

Output after select:

[image]

[image]

But I would like to have only one select query which will chose table to join based on XOR (which id_user in sample data is not null).

Comment: Please some sample data and expected output also.

Comment: Hello, I added this to the question.

Comment: @LubosJansky Please post those queries as text, not as paintings

Comment: By "*this table is in XOR with tables*" you mean that each row has either the one foreign key or the other?

Comment: You'll want to use outer joins: `LEFT JOIN … ON`